# Map Relationship between three tables and show it on View using Vaadin + SpringBoot

Tags: orm, spring-boot, vaadin, relationships

Tryng to learn Vaadin plus SpringBoot relationships and view components by example using this projetc as base [KumoReg, Convention Registration Management](https://github.com/jashort/kumoreg).

It has a lot of entities, but I'm adapting it to a more complex Entity–relationship model where:

1. A Role has a new relatioship Skill: one to many.
2. Skill has Type: many to one.
3. When link a Skill to a Role, it has a Level (SkillLevel). Example:

   - Role[Senior Software Developer] has Skill[Spanish] with Level[Fluent]
   - Role[Jr Software Developer] has Skill[Spanish] with Level[Basic]

I have the entities Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -586627565466025158L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Right> rights;

    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //private Set<SkillSkillLevel> skillSkillLevels;

    public Role() {
        this.rights = new HashSet<Right>();
        //this.skillSkillLevels = new HashSet<SkillSkillLevel>();
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addRight(Right right) {
        rights.add(right);
    }

    public void addRights(Set<Right> rights) {
        this.rights.addAll(rights);
    }

    public void removeRight(String right) {
        rights.remove(right);
    }

    public Set<Right> getRights() {
        return new HashSet<Right>(rights);
    }

    public boolean hasRight(String name) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        if (name == null) {
            return false;
        }
        for (Right r : rights) { 
            if (r.getName().equals(name) || r.getName().equals("super_admin")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void clearRights() {
        this.rights.clear();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Role))
            return false;
        if (this.getId() == null) {
            return this == other;
        } else {
            Role o = (Role) other;
            return this.getId().equals(o.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    }
```

Skill:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skills")
public class Skill implements Serializable, Comparable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8126472682725739996L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s", name);
    }

    public Skill() {}

    public Skill(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Skill))
            return false;
        if (this.getId() == null) {
            return this == other;
        } else {
            Skill o = (Skill) other;
            return this.getId().equals(o.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    }

    public Integer getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof Skill) {
            Skill other = (Skill)o;
            return name.compareTo(other.getName());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

SkillLevel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skillLevels")
public class SkillLevel implements Serializable, Comparable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8126472682725739996L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s", name);
    }

    public SkillLevel() {}

    public SkillLevel(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof SkillLevel))
            return false;
        if (this.getId() == null) {
            return this == other;
        } else {
            SkillLevel o = (SkillLevel) other;
            return this.getId().equals(o.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getName().hashCode();
    }

    public Integer getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof SkillLevel) {
            SkillLevel other = (SkillLevel)o;
            return name.compareTo(other.getName());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Should I have to create a new Entity called RoleSkillLevel to set the table will join the three ids (role_skill_level) or there is a better way to create it?

And on Role View, when creating new role_skill_level entries, what should be a useful UI component to add and delete lines of Skill + Level?

Comment: i'd keep out all of that ORM/DB stuff as far away from the GUI as possible.  build your GUI with whatever represents the data for the GUI best; use some CQRS layer for your domain model. as for the UI component, imagine, what would you as user like to get your work done fast?  could be a table/grid, could be something adding components into some layout.  wrap that into a CustomField and make that deal with your UI model.

Comment: you are mixing database model with business model with view model. You should isolate all database related entities for only database operations. Put you business logic with a new model that you deduce it from database model. Then you should pass data that you need to view on UI in business model and deal with them ..  Try to use in view UI simple data structure as much as you can. You can build you view (a vaadin table or grid for example) with only String values. hope this guides you !!!